# Remove the strings starting with # and everything after #

Tags: linux, awk, sed

How can I remove the substrings starting with `#` and everything after `#`?

There are many of them on different lines; they all start with `#` and are at the end of the line, and the number at the end is always different. They are all 15 characters long; I want to delete everything from `#` through the end of the line, with sed or awk.

```
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/xyz/fred-episode-110#group=p02q32xl
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/abc/simon-episode-266#group=p03d924k
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/qwe/mum-episode-39#group=p03l1jpr
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/zxc/dad-episode-41#group=p03l1j9s
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/asd/bob-episode-57#group=p03l1j7g
```

Comment: sed -e   's/#.$//'    infile.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- With `cut` – declare `#` as the field separator and print only the first field:

  ```
  cut -d '#' -f 1 infile
  ```
- With sed – replace everything from `#` on with the empty string:

  ```
  sed 's/#.*//' infile
  ```
- With awk – declare `#` as field separator and print the first field:

  ```
  awk -F'#' '{ print $1 }' infile
  ```
- With Bash, taking advantage of the fact that it's always the last 15 characters:

  ```
  while IFS= read -r line; do
      echo "${line:0:-15}"
  done < infile
  ```

  Notice that this is a) very slow and b) requires Bash 4.2-alpha or newer to support the negative length value in the parameter expansion.
- With Perl – splitting by `#`, taking the first field of the list and printing it with `say` to include a newline:

  ```
  perl -nE 'say ((split /#/)[0])' infile
  ```

  or, more concise and sed-ish (pointed out my [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)):

  ```
  perl -pe 's/#.*//' infile
  ```

Comment: **sed 's/#.*$//' infile**  will match from # (inclusive) to final character on same line.

Comment: @ArifBurhan Yes, I think that's the way it should be: remove the last 15 characters, which includes `#`.

Comment: thank you all for your help i used one of Benjamin ways sed 's/#.*//' infile and added -i  like Arif Burhan said   sed -i 's/#.*//' infile  and it worked

Comment: ++, but, I suggest you mention that a Bash loop will be sloooooooooow (and your solution requires Bash v4+); a clone of the `sed` solution makes for a simpler Perl solution: `perl -pe 's/#.*//' infile`

Comment: @bob: Actually Arif used `-e`, which is not needed, but I'm glad you found `-i`, which updates the input file in place (sort of). Also, I've edited the question to make it clearer that you do _not_ want the `#` included.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks, amended!

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Benjamin W.'s helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w):

`grep` is another option:

- If you do NOT want to include the `#`:

  ```
  grep -Eo '^[^#]+' file
  ```
- If you DO want to include the `#`:

  ```
  grep -Eo '^[^#]+.' file
  ```

Answer (score 0):

[Using Python Regex](https://regex101.com/r/kF0yV6/1)`(.*?)(#.*)` and substituting with `\1`: